# Alternative to untyped DataTable when working with variable columns?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I am working with a data source (right now Excel sheets, but also in the future a database) which returns a table with a variable numer of columns (besides a few predefined ones).

Right now I am using a DataTable in order to explore the columns of each table. But ideally I would like to map the datatables to my own model objects. But of course the issue is that objects should have a set of compile-time defined properties.

Does a better approach exist? Or should I stick to DataRow/DataTable? What I am doing is considering each DataRow as an object with "dynamic" fields. I.e, I just get a list of the columns of the DataTable.

Comment: There is no answer to this because it really depends on the situation. For instance microsoft also has strong typed datasets and the normal ones and both have their place in the framework.

Comment: Define "better". If you don't know the columns in advance, then obviously you cannot have statically defined classes to encapsulate them. Whether you use `dynamic` or `Dictionary` or just manually enumerate columns has little impact on solving whatever problem you're solving.

Comment: If you don't know about columns in advance, then you simply can't do this

Comment: The issue is that in the future the data source may be something like MongoDB or Cassandra. I am not sure if a DataTable is the best way to go with no-SQL databases. But it seems it is my only option. Or just creating a list of field names and value (untyped) for each table column, but this would be quite similar to a DataTable and reinveintg the wheel is a loss of time.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: actually I liked your idea. A `Dictionary<string, object>` could be an elegant solution.